# Blender rigify not creating head bone

Tags: rigging, armature, unity, rigify

Hi im new to blender and is currently making a game in unity, but i need to make a 3d model for my game. The model has to be humanoid and therefore i need a head, but when creating the rigify armature i only get 6 spines and a face. I dont know of anything i can do with that. Because my character does not have a face, and head bone is required.

Anyone know what i can do to fix this? or if im doing something wrong?

EDIT: Tha picture of the rigged model was a simple armature and not the one im refering to. And i can still not move the head because its not a head bone its the 6th spine.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts I have added it now :)

Comment: I've taken a quick look, and I see your problem, but the solution is going to take a while to write up.  Meanwhile, it's best not to delete bones from the meta rig.  Generate a rig and delete unneeded bones from it.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you, but seems a little weird that you should do it that way. Youtube tutorials ive seen always deletes before generating a rig... but there arent a lot of tutorials out there on rigging, or at least i havent found much.

Comment: It's probably more a matter of preferences than anything else.  Since my regen from your modified metarig works, maybe whatever happened to you wasn't rigify being confused; but my answer will at least get you going again.

Comment: Do you have a way of exporting the model you created to fbx and can you see if the head bone comes with? Because my head bone is not being exported with fbx.... 
https://gyazo.com/3a5201fb92dcd65d403eb3345372c629

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that when you deleted the face from the meta rig, you confused rigify about what should be the head.  Until you've become proficient at rigify you should never modify a metarig.  Even when you are proficient it's better to generate a rig and modify it.

Rather than have you go all the way back and edit a metarig to fit your A pose, here's a suggestion:

1. Get rid of the currently generated rig.

   - select `Body` in object mode.
   - remove all of the vertex groups.

     - go to the *Object Data Properties* Tab
     - Use the ↓ menu and select *Delete All Groups*
   - Unparent `Body` from the armature:

     - Go to *Object Properties* Tab
     - Open the *Relations* panel
     - click on the 'x' to remove `rig` as the parent.
   - Delete the armature modifier

     - Go to the *Modifiers* Tab
     - Click on the 'x' to remove `Armature` modifier.
2. Delete the rig.  (*not* the metarig)
3. Generate a new rig.
4. Parent the `body` to the new `rig` using *Automatic Weights*

At this point, in WireFrame Mode, your head area should look like this:

[image: Screenshot showing rig in wireframe mode]

The cyan circle is the control that will move your head.  It is considered part of the Torso in the Rig UI

Here's a fixed version of your rig.

[image]